# Bootstrap 5 spinner not spinning on Firefox

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Basically what the title says. A super simple bootstrap 5 spinner actually doesn't spin in Firefox. Tested with Chromium everything works fine. All other bootstrap components work fine in Firefox too.

The html code is the following (identical to Bootstrap docs):

```
<div class="spinner-border" role="status">
  <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
</div>
```

The Firefox version is 102.12.0esr (I thought it might be the esr version but checked on another pc with 102.14.0esr and it works. I don't know if that's related to a 102.12 specific bug because I didn't manage to find anything related. I checked for updates but there aren't available, I'm on CentOS 9 Stream).

Probably I'm missing something super easy but I really don't understand what. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**  I tested as instructed in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion) and I noticed that, when I disable the reduced motion property (in Firefox), the animation is more sluggish that what it should be (checked on another machine). Don't know where this configuration is coming from tho. But definitively not a misconfiguration in browser reduced motion preference.

**UPDATE 2:** To clarify, the spinner don't work on the [official bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/spinners/) page too, so it's most probably a browser/config problem... or some other config parameter I have to force someway in the code but I don't know how to do it, if it's even possible...

Comment: Sounds like it's just a problem with your browser. The fact that Firefox won't let you update it is your issue. I don't think this is anything related to your code.

Comment: Have you used your  browser devtools inspect facility to check exactly what CSS is being used here? Then check e.g. on caniuse.com to see if every property is supported in version12.

Comment: @Caleb I checked the browser setting as stated on [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-reduced-motion) and I see the difference when I enable the `ui.prefersReducedMotion` in Firefox, still no difference in the spinners tho. I'll edit the question with some other tests I've done.

Comment: @AHaworth just checked and the bootstrap css is used correctly. The spinner animation is just a basic animation and checking the bootstrap css file, all properties are vastly supported by Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try to test the spinners on this page
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/spinners/#about

Comment: Ye, they don't work there either, so it's most likely a browser problem, but I don't know where I should look to understand why this feature works like that... on other firefox instances on other PCs everything is fine... I'll put that in an update anyway, thx

Comment: Yes, it turns out to be the problem of your browser because I have Mozilla Firefox 106.0.1 and all the spinners work fine.

Comment: This is not an answer but a suggestion, this is better suited to a comment than leaving an answer